# How to perform dynamic add, delete and save with nested viewmodels in knockoutjs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

In MVC, You can have the following view model:

```
public class MyCVViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Resume Title cannot exceed 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Resume Title")]
    public string ResumeTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Personal Statment cannot exceed 1000 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Personal Statement")]
    public string Statement { get; set; }

    public List<MyCompanyViewModel> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class MyCompanyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Company Name cannot exceed 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Job Title cannot exceed 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime JobStartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime JobEndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Job Description cannot exceed 1000 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Job Description")]
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

MyCVViewModel have a list of MyCompanyViewModels, this is pretty straightforward.

I am starting to learn knockoutjs and tried to duplicate the same view model within knockoutjs.

Here is what i've tried so far:

```
//company viewmodel
function Company(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    //other stuff
}

//cv view model
function CVViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.oberservable();
    self.statement = ko.oberservalbe();
    //list of company view model
    self.companies = ko.observableArray();

    //add company
    self.addCompany = function () {
        self.companies.push({
            name: ""
        });
    };

    //remove company
    self.removeCompany = function (company) {
        self.companies.remove(company);
    };

    //populate with json
    $.getJSON("/Class/FillCompany", function (allData) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Company(item) });
        self.companies(mappedTasks);
    });
};

// Activate knockout binding
ko.applyBindings(new CVViewModel());
```

Adding and deleting works fine, but I am not sure how to save the entire cv viewmodel and post it to a controller in asp.net mvc.

Most of the tutorials online post the child viewmodel(in my case list of companies) and post it to server but not the parent viewmodel(in my case cvviewmdoel).

so in my view I can only post the companies to server:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <textarea name="companies" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(companies)"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

and in my controller I expect a list of companies:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([FromJson] IEnumerable<Company> companies)
{
    //save to database etc..
}
```

How do i post the entire parent view model so that my controller looks something more like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(MyCVViewModel cv)
{
    //save to database etc..
}
```

in which MyCVViewModel contains list of companies already.

Comment: Just post the main viewModel, using ko.toJSON. If you have things named alike on the server side it will map to your server side objects magically.

Comment: just post like this `ko.toJSON(self)` it should work if your models are same in both ends , cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little programming on the client you can make this work.

First of all you may want to save yourself some time unless you need to something with each company that can't be handled with subscribers by using ko.mapping

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, {} self.companies)
```

Also when adding a new company you will want to keep it an observable so use:

```
self.companies.push(new Company(name));
```

You can send the entire model header and children as a json object to match your server side object.

So change your view model to the following:

```
function viewModel()
{
   var self = this;

   self.title = ko.oberservable();
   self.statement = ko.oberservalbe();
   //list of company view model
   self.companies = ko.observableArray();

   //add company
   self.addCompany = function () {
      self.companies.push(new Company(name));
   };

   //remove company
   self.removeCompany = function (company) {
       self.companies.remove(company);
   };

   //populate with json
   $.getJSON("/Class/FillCompany", function (allData) {
       ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, {} self.companies)
   });

   //save
   saveModel = function(){
        var data = ko.mapping.toJS(self);
        $ajax({
        url: 'Class/SaveCompany',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
           //do success stuff here.
        }

   }
```

Then on your submit, bind your click event to the view model save event and it will send up a parent model with all the children as a single form post.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, since posting the question, I've figured it out, do you need ko.mapping js file to use ko.mapping.

Comment: Yes you will need to include ko.mapping.  makes roundtrips on ajax requests so much easier to manage.